# How to detect/track postback in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, postback

How to detect/track/check postback in javascript(e.g in asp.net Page.isPostBack())? 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

ASPX:

```
<input type="hidden" id="_ispostback" value="<%=Page.IsPostBack.ToString()%>" />
```

Client-side Script:

```
function isPostBack() { //function to check if page is a postback-ed one
  return document.getElementById('_ispostback').value == 'True';
}
```

PS: I have not tested it but I've done somthing similar before and it works.

Comment: As a matter or preference I add runat="server" to the hidden input and change it's value in the codebehind file but this works just fine. And I would recommend jQuery to do the javascript because that would become: function isPostBack() {return $("#_ispostback").val() == 'true';}

Comment: @Shhnap: Yes I agree. Just a lazy way out for me :P

Comment: Why bother inserting an `<input>` element?  You could just have isPostBack() directly return the value of Page.IsPostBack:  `return <%= Page.IsPostBack %>;`

Comment: @RickNZ: That's a pretty good idea. Post as answer, I'll up-vote it :)

Comment: Sure: I added it to my earlier answer.

Comment: There is a reason why a hidden field is better, just using a javascript function will only load this value on actual post back, but for asynch postback it will not, using an input field within a an update panel that is set to updatemode=always, will make this work even on asynch postbacks.

Comment: This falls down when code-blocks aren't allowed. What would you do in that instance?

Comment: Slight variation for culture and language invariance `<%=Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : ""%>` ..... which enables javascript to be more succint too

`if (document.getElementById('_ispostback').value) doStuff();`

Answer (score 22):

In some cases, you may want to check for postback without any server-side code.  For example, in SharePoint, you cannot have code blocks in SharePoint Designer pages, so you can't use any solution that requires <%=something %>.  Here is an alternative that involves no server-side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function isPostBack()
 {

  return document.referrer.indexOf(document.location.href) > -1;
 }

 if (isPostBack()){
document.write('<span style="color:red;">Your search returned no results.</span><br/>');
 }
 </script>
```

One caveat (or feature, depending on how you look at it), this will detect not just postbacks, but any instance where the page links to itself.

Comment: var offset = document.location.href.indexOf(".aspx");
return document.referrer.substring(0, offset + 5) == document.location.href.substring(0, offset + 5)

Comment: This worked great for me. thanks :) I had a javacript redirect that needed to check for postback.

Comment: What a kludge. Don't use the referrer for logic.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to check whether the current page will be a postback if the user clicks on a submit button, you can check for the presence of ViewState:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="xxxxx" />
```

You can use something like `document.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE")` or the jQuery equivalent.

However, if you want to see whether the current page was generated in response to a postback, then you need to insert that data into the page on the server side first.

For example:

```
function isPostBack() {
  return <%= Page.IsPostBack %>;
}
```

Comment: This falls down if you don't have access to server-side code and code blocks aren't allowed.

Comment: Oddly, that does not work for me but this does:    function IsPostBack() {
     var ret = '<%= Page.IsPostBack%>' == 'True';
     return ret;
   }

Answer (score 6):

As JavaScript shouldn't be written with server-side code, and injecting new elements into the page seems like overkill, it seems to me that the simplest solution is to add [`[datat-*]`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-data-*) attributes to the `<head>` element:

<sub>In Page_Load:</sub>

```
Page.Header.Attributes["data-is-postback"] IsPostBack ? "true" : "false";
```

This can then be accessed as:

<sub>jQuery:</sub>

```
$('head').data('isPostback');
```

<sub>Vanilla JS:</sub>

```
document.head.getAttribute('data-is-postback') === 'true';
```

Of course, if you treat the `[data-is-postback]` attribute as a boolean attribute, you could alternatively use:

<sub>In Page_Load:</sub>

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    Page.Header.Attributes.Add("data-is-postback", "");
}
else
{
    Page.Header.Attributes.Remove("data-is-postback");
}
```

<sub>jQuery:</sub>

```
$('head').is('[data-is-postback]');
```

<sub>Vanilla JS:</sub>

```
document.head.hasAttribute('data-is-postback')
```

Comment: While this is great if you access to server-side code, it falls down if you don't. Some software doesn't even allow code blocks, so a pure JavaScript solution would be needed.

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution that worked for me.

```
// Postback catch
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function (s, e) {
    alert("post back");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

See following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function invokeMeMaster() {

var chkPostBack = '<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>';

if (chkPostBack == 'false') {

alert('Only the first time');

}
}



window.onload = function() { invokeMeMaster(); };

</script>
```

Comment: I love your choice of names.

Answer (score 0):

You can only keep track of the postback if you are using AJAX requests or have a hidden field of some sort that the javascript reads on page load. Otherwise the page is regenerated and all POST data is lost; as you would expect and hope.

Answer (score 0):

on Page_Load on your server-side :
The following uses an overload of RegisterClientScriptBlock() that will surround our string with the needed script tags

Server-Side

```
if (Page.IsPostBack){
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(),
            "IsPostBack", "var isPostBack = true;", true);
}
```

Then in your script which runs for the onLoad, check for the existence of that variable.

```
if (isPostBack){
   //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for ASP.Net pages without relying on a backend supplied variable/control:

```
function isPostBack(frmID) {
    var eventtarget = "";
    var eventargument = "";

    if (!!frmID) {
        if (document.forms.length == 0) return false;

        sForm = document.forms[0];
    }
    else {
        sForm = document.getElementById(frmID);

        if (!sForm) return false;
    }

    if (sForm.__EVENTTARGET) eventtarget = sForm.__EVENTTARGET.value;
    else return false;

    if (sForm.__EVENTARGUMENT) eventargument = sForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value;
    else return false;

    if (eventtarget != "" || eventargument != "") return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple JS way to determine the status of IsPostBack that I just got working in the Body of my ASPX page; needed to cause a PostBack during PageLoad for a project.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ('False' === '<%= Page.IsPostBack.ToString()%>') 
        {
            __doPostBack();
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution using jQuery:

```
$("a[href^='javascript:__doPostBack']").click(function () {
    alert('ok');
});
```