# catch ispostback event javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to catch Ispostback event using javascript for some purpose. I found many example in google but none of them has worked for me.
Like one example i used which is below:

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
   var chkPostBack = '<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>';
        if (chkPostBack == 'true') {
            alert("Ispostback alert");
        }
        
});
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Have you already seen this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857606/how-to-detect-track-postback-in-javascript?

Comment: Yes this i have tried also but it is also not working.

Comment: Also check for another suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59719/how-can-i-check-for-ispostback-in-javascript. Provide additional details if you feel current code is not complete enough.

Comment: I have checked this example also as given here i used if condition to check ispostback in pageload event code behind then i put javascript function first outside of document.ready function. It was not working then i put this function inside document.ready but that one is also not working.

Comment: It is working just fine. I get an alert on PostBack.

Comment: which solution you used the one which i mentioned here? if yes then how did you used. Please explain.